# Delete specific folders older than 2 weeks with some exceptions

Tags: powershell

I need to delete just the workspace folder, older than 2 weeks, contained in various job folders in a particular directory.

**Example**: My root directory `C:\DeleteTest` contains 4 folders:

```
Job1
Job2
Job3
Job4
```

Each of those folders contains a list of files and a `workspace` folder.
I need to delete just this `workspace` folder which are *older than 2 weeks* with the *exception* of the workspace folder from `Job2`.

Comment: why job2? what criteria?

Comment: It's just a for instance. There's a list of jobs which are older 2 weeks that shouldn't be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would invoke the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet twice. The first time, to retrieve all subfolders of `C:\DeleteTest` where you exclude all folders within `$excludeFolders`. The second time you retrieve all workspace directories within this folders and filter them by the desired creation time. Finally, delete the folder using the `Remove-Item` cmdlet:

```
$excludeFolders = @('Job2')
Get-ChildItem C:\DeleteTest -Directory | Where Name -NotIn $excludeFolders |
     Get-ChildItem -Filter 'workspace' -Directory | Where { $_.CreationTime -le (Get-Date).Adddays(-14) } |
     Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem C:\DeleteTest -Directory -Filter Workspace | % {
  if ($_.Parent.Name -notin $array_of_folders_not_to_be_deleted -and $_.CreationTime -le (Get-Date).Adddays(-14)) {
    Remove-Item $_.FullName -Recurse -Force 
    }
}
```

be careful, `-notin` expects a complete match, so `Job2` and `Job` won't match.

Comment: Wouldn't this delete all the files and folders in the jobs folder? I need just the folder 'workspace' to be deleted from each of the job folders.

Comment: well, in that case you would want to modify the answer to suit your needs, i've updated it

Comment: For instance if each job folder had 'workspace' folder, a 'test' folder and 3 doc files.

Comment: Are you aware that you are not checking for the creationtime of the workspace folders but for job1, job2, job3....? Because he was asking about deleting the workspace folders which are older than 2 weeks

Comment: oh dang, hold on, let me fix this. thanks! didin't notice that

Answer (score -1):

```
gci "C:\temp\DeleteTest\Job*\workspace" -directory | 
    ? { $_.FullName -notlike "C:\temp\DeleteTest\Job2\*" -and $_.CreationTime -le (get-date).AddDays(-14)} | 
        Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```